# Applying interceptor to Jersey RESTful service wired as Spring @Component

Tags: spring, jersey, interceptor

Is it possible to apply a Spring handler interceptor or something similar to a Jersey Restful service? The Jersey service is built with Spring and is inside a Spring @Component?

I noticed that Spring allows the use of handler interceptors for controllers but cant find anything to work with my Jersey-Rest component

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jersey comes with its own servlet and therefore is pretty much outside of Spring MVC, which the Interceptors are part of. You can either:

- Use a Spring HTTP Filter to massage the HTTPServletRequest and the HTTPServletResponse around Jersey
- Use a Spring Handled Aspect around your Spring Component inside of Jersey to massage the Method invocation and result.

This guy here did a great job summing up the nuts and bolts: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/

Comment: cheers. I was already aware of how to configure rest with spring so that part of your answer is not so helpful however overall it leads me to the answer.

Comment: @cduggan what was the answer you came up with?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and this how I [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35727497/is-there-an-interceptor-in-jersey-similar-to-that-of-springs-handlerinterceptor) it in Jersey.
This works similar to HandleInterceptor of Spring.