# Is there an Interceptor in Jersey similar to that of Spring's HandlerInterceptor

Tags: spring, filter, servlet-filters, interceptor, jersey-2.0

I need an Interceptor in Jersey 2.x which gives references to request, response and the Method which matched the Path to a Web Service.

Something similar to **HandlerInterceptor** of Spring.

Requirements:

1. **Need Annotations used on Class** - Perform the below checks, Only if the corresponding Method which needs to be invoked by jersey is NOT Annotated with a custom annotation.
2. **Request** - To get/set attributes and get Session Object to validate user.
3. **Response** - To re-direct the call in case any validation fails even before invoking the corresponding Methos.

Spring equivalent code:

```
public class WebServiceInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
     @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        try {
            SkipWebServiceIntercept skipWebService = handler.getClass().getAnnotation(SkipWebServiceIntercept.class);

            if (skipWebService != null) {
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }

            ...

            if(securityFails)
            {
                if ("XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"))) {
                    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    String json;
                    ...
                    out.println(json);
                    return Boolean.FALSE;
                }
                else {
                    response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in preHandle, redirecting to Login page", e);
            return LoginUtil.redirectToLogin(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

I found references of

1. **ReaderInterceptor** - This provides just Annotations of the Class. No access to request/response.
2. **ContainerRequestFilter** - Provides Request Object but no Annotations/Response.
3. **ContainerResponseFilter** - Gives Request & Response. But after the web-service/Method is invoked.

Is there anyother way this can be achieved without using Filters. because I need this processing to happen ONLY if the corresponding web-service is present.
Filter's with /* on the other hand would always perform these validations even when the resource was not found.

**Edit:**
Thanks to @peeskillet [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35736830/1925997) This is how I implemented it.

```
@Provider
public class ResourceInterceptor implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {

        System.out.println("Resource Interceptor called");

        if (resourceInfo.getResourceClass() != null
                && resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotation(SkipWebServiceIntercept.class) != null)
            return;

        context.register(LoginFilter.class);
    }

}


@Slf4j
public class LoginFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest      request;

    @Context
    private ServletContext          servletContext;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        try {


WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);

CookieAuthenticator cookieAuthenticator = springContext.getBean(CookieAuthenticator.class);

HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

...
```

> // Sending JSON/Object back as response

```
...
String json = gson.toJson(resposeJson);

Response response = new ResponseBuilderImpl().encoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
                        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(json).build();
requestContext.abortWith(response);
...
```

> // or Sending URL back

```
...
URI uri = new URI(baseUrl + redirectUrl + "?refback=" + url);
requestContext.abortWith(Response.temporaryRedirect(uri).build());
...
```

Both the approaches worked perfectly, similar to HandlerInterceptor of Spring.

Comment: Thanks for going back and updating with a working solution.  I have it all working, but I don't understand what SkipWebServiceIntercept is.  How was this created?

Comment: Nevermind, I just created a Custom annotation

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface SkipWebServiceIntercept {
   String value() default "";
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anyother way this can be achieved without using Filters. because I need this processing to happen ONLY if the corresponding web-service is present. Filter's with /* on the other hand would always perform these validations even when the resource was not found.

There are different ways to register a filter.

1. Just register it normally, where the result is the filter *always* getting called. (what you don't want).
2. Registered with an annotation, though [name binding](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9988). This way, only resource annotated will go through the filter. (this is *kind of* what you want, only problem is you would need to annotate every class)

   ```
   @Target({TYPE, METHOD})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME);
   class @interface Filtered {}

   @Path("..")
   @Filtered
   public class YourResource {}

   @Filtered
   @Provider
   public class YourFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {}
   ```
3. [Use a DynamicFeature](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e10061) to bind resource programmatically, rather than declaratively. The `DynamicFeture` will get called for each of your resource *methods*, so you can just register the filter for *every* call. This has the same affect as annotating every resource class (as mentioned above) with name binding (this is probably what you want).

   ```
   @Provider
   public class MyFeature implements DynamicFeature {
       @Override
       public void configure(ResourceInfo ri, FeatureContext ctx) {
           ctx.register(YourFilter.class);
       }
   }
   ```

**See Also:**

- [Chapter 10. Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e10061)

Comment: The problem with using `ContainerRequestFilter` is that I won't have response object with me. I can access ResourceInfo to check annotations but if validation fails then I'll have to re-direct from the filter itself without invoking the resource.
Using **Servlet Filter** I can use response.sendRedirect() to achieve this. How do I use  ContainerRequestFilter to do this? I explored all API's of ContainerRequestContext and I was unable to find the response.
So is there a way to redirect to another URL from ContainerRequestFilter as well?

Comment: You can use `requestContext.abortWith(Response)`... (`Response.seeOther(...)` for redirect)

Comment: Or you can throw an exception and handle the redirect in an [ExceptionMapper](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6665)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try these approach and update. 
Also how to register DynamicFeature in jersey web.xml? I wrote a DynamicFeature but the configure method is not getting invoked.

Comment: If you are scanning for your resources by package, i.e. you have the init-param `jersey.config.server.provider.packages`, you can use more than one package, just separate them by comma. The package scanning picks up the `@Provider` annotation. Or you can explicitly register the class with the init-param `jersey.config.server.provider.classnames`

Comment: I tried loading httpServletResponse in filter and using sendRedirect. Redirection works, however it doesn't stop the resource from getting called.
Also, I've a piece of code where I may need to get the `PrintWriter` from `HttpServletResponse` and write an error output in the writer.
This doesn't work with this approach. If I make use of Response for Jax-rs then I won't be able to half of these. I guess the only option I've is to use a ServletFilter instead of using Jersey-Filter.
Any Idea if we can register `ServletFilter` in `DynamicFeature`, I tried but didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `requestContext.abortWith(Response)`?