# Cannot inject ResourceInfo into ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: jersey, guice, grizzly

I'm trying to implement a ContainerRequestFilter that checks some stuff. Ultimately, it shall authenicate a token, but I'm not there yet. The filter runs on a Grizzly HTTP Server (Grizzly 2.3.4) and sits in front of a JAX-RS resource (Jersey 2.0). I am also using Guice 3.0.

When I'm trying to inject javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo into the filter, it is null.

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {

        String method = containerRequestContext.getMethod();
        System.out.println("method = " + method);

        if("OPTIONS".equals(method)) return;

        System.out.println("DO SECURITY");
    }
}
```

Injecting the request into a JAX-RS resource, the injection is successful and I can work with it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey. I believe what you do is resource specific authentication, correct? your approach would work, however you would usually implement that feature with a dynamic feature first. I have an example if you are interested, please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732360/how-to-optionally-protect-a-resource-with-custom-dropwizard-filter (don't get spooked by the dropwizard in the question, it answers it for generic jersey)

Comment: If you need access to ResourceInfo and then apply filter on it, I would recommend trying DynamicFeature. My question mentioned here, has a solution about how to use these features. http://stackoverflow.com/q/35727497/1925997

Comment: I did the authentication without the ResourceInfo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable injection in `ContainerRequestFilter` you have to annotate it as `@Provider`, then it works

```
@Provider
public class MyRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    ...
}
```