# Spring Boot HandlerInterceptor not firing when Jersey Configured?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jersey

I have a Spring Boot v1.4.0 application configured with Jersey for delivery of RESTful services.

I have a working app, but I'm now trying to enhance it with a multi-tenancy SCHEMA awareness strategy. I was hoping to set a TenantContext based on client auth headers using a Spring's HandlerInterceptor framework...

BUT, there seems to be an issue with the Interceptors being fired with Jersey. I can hit the APIs fine, ( i.e. *curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/products* ), but the interceptors just won't fire. If I wire up a more basic app without Jersey for resource management, they fire fine?

Here is the current application set-up:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

Registering the Interceptor

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    HandlerInterceptor tenantInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(tenantInterceptor);
    }
}
```

The Interceptor itself

```
@Component
public class TenantInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // FIXME: Put in a Logger impl
        System.out.println("++++++++++++=======+++++++++ TenantInterceptor.preHandle() Checking for Tenant Routing");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        TenantContext.clear();
        // FIXME: Put in a Logger impl
        System.out.println("++++++++++++=======+++++++++ TenantInterceptor.postHandle() Reset Tenant to " + TenantContext.getCurrentTenant());
    }
}
```

The JerseyConfig

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        registerClasses(TenantsResource.class);
        registerClasses(UsersResource.class);
        registerClasses(ProductsResource.class);
    }

}
```

I played around with the JerseyConfig *@ApplicationPath("api")* and the WebMvcConfig *registry.addInterceptor(tenantInterceptor).addPathPatterns("patterns");*.  Tried the following one after the other, but no joy.

```
registry.addInterceptor(tenantInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/*");

registry.addInterceptor(tenantInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");

registry.addInterceptor(tenantInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/api/**");

registry.addInterceptor(tenantInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/api/*");

registry.addInterceptor(tenantInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/api/products");

registry.addInterceptor(tenantInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/api/products/");
```

Any help - much appreciated, or else I'll be resorting to hacking the Resource Controllers with smelly code :(.

Thanks - Derm

Comment: Well no... `HandlerInterceptor` is a Spring MVC thing not a Jersey thing.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the response! O.K. So I can't register HandlerInterceptors with Jersey Servlets. Any idea on a clean alternative - Filters?

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your direction.. I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/13816147/2240475 which gives alternative approaches by Stefan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by M.Deinum, `HandlerInterceptor` is not for Jersey, and it not some "underversal" interceptor. It is only for Spring MVC. For Jersey, you can use a [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html). You would register it with you ResourceConfig.

**See also:**

- [Jersey docs for Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)